# React: Passing parameters in Dumb Component Functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

So I am in the process of working on a sort of "intermediate" level react project. I know the basics, but don't know best practices on some things.

Lets pretend I am passing a function to a "Dumb" component, in this dumb component is a button that is a callback to a parent function `Editname` which looks like this:

```
editName = (id) => {
    console.log(`Name edited for ${id}`);
}
```

In the "Dumb" component there is a button that calls this since it's being passed as a prop from it's parent:

```
<button type="input" onClick={props.editName}>Edit</button>
```

However the problem is, I need to pass along the `id` as well to the callback function (I get the `id` as a prop in the dumb component as well). What's the best way to go about this? I know one option is:

`{()=> {props.editName(props.id)}` but i've been told this is a bad practice because the function will get created everytime. So what is the "proper" way to do this? Or do I need to make it as a class and handle it as a callback to another function within the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid creating the function everytime, you can attach an identifier to the target element using `data-*` attributes and then make use of it further.

For example:

```js
<button type="input" onClick={props.editName} data-id="edit-button">Edit</button>
```

And then, in the function, you can have this:

```js
editName = event => {
  const id = event.target.getAttribute("data-id");
  console.log(`Name edited for ${id}`);
};
```

You can very well take the `data-id` from the props:

```js
<button type="input" onClick={props.editName} data-id={props.id}>Edit</button>
```

How you would want to manage the `data-id` attribute will depend upon the use case.

---

This might not be *the proper* way, as OP has asked, but it does reduce the number of functions created everytime.

Comment: This is kinda redundant given that you can just access `id` from `this.props` (or `props` if you're using hooks) inside `editName` eg `editName = () => { console.log(this.props.id); };`

Comment: Agreed; I assumed that the Component is a functional component -- given that OP said it is "dumb". And, the callback function is defined outside of the functional component where you would not have access to `props` or `this`

Comment: This is correct ^, the callback function is defined in it's parent component.

Answer (score 1):

For good practice you should use destructuring in your code like...

```
const { editName, id } = props;
<button type="input" onClick={editName} data-id={id}>Edit</button>
```

For destructuring practices folllow this link.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Couldn't I destructure them directly in the `(props)` parameter? Or does that not work for dumb components?